# How to add one post at a time from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed a tutorial to get a timeline going.  In the tutorial he uses `.Value` when retrieving data from Firebase. I later learned that it isn't very efficient because it re-downloads everything whenever a post is added.  This causes all user's timelines to flash and auto-scroll.

I'm trying to convert this to use `.childAdded` but can't figure out how to get it to work. This is the current code:

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child("\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { postDictionary in
if postDictionary.exists() {
    if let snapshots = postDictionary.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        self.posts = []
        for snap in snapshots {
            if let postDict = snap.value as? NSDictionary {
                for(name, value) in postDict {
                    let interval = postDict.objectForKey("timePosted") as! Double
                    let formattedDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
                    let timeAgo = self.getDate(formattedDate)
                    if name as! String == "postedBy" {
                        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(value as! String).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (userDictionary) in
                            let userDict = userDictionary.value as! NSDictionary
                            let username = userDict.objectForKey("username")!
                            let profileThumbUrl = userDict.objectForKey("profileThumbUrl")!
                            let key = snap.key
                            let post = Post(postKey: key, dictionary: postDict, username: username as! String, profileThumbUrl: profileThumbUrl as! String, timeAgo: timeAgo)
                            self.posts.append(post)
                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
})
```

The 2nd Firebase call is just grabbing user info for the user thumbnail and username.  When I change `.Value` at the top to `.ChildAdded`, nothing shows up on the timeline. I have tried messing around with filetypes etc. and can't get it to work.

***Update***

Okay so after reading another Firebase question on here it looks like `.ChildAdded` gets just the child added. I was thinking it got the same data, just that the whole thing would run when a child was added.

So it looks like I'm going to have to change the loops here and run a loop adding each child added one by one. Going to redo the whole thing and will post the difference when I finish it if I can get it working.

Comment: Using `.Value` of `.Child...` doesn't make any difference in the wire traffic. The only difference is in how you update the UI. So while it is indeed better to use the Child events here, the reason is that it results in a smoother UI, no in less bandwidth usage.

Comment: Yeah my original problem is that when a child is added my whole collectionview flashes and scrolls to the top.  I found out though it's going to do that either way and I think I have to do the batch update thing to add a cell without scrolling or something.